# Selling unrealised stock position to reduce taxes, then buying again. Am I off the hook?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, stock-markets, capital-gains-tax

I have a realised profit for the current year of **$1000**. (On which I will be required to pay taxes).

I have another position that is unrealised (still holding the stock) that is negative **$1000**.

Now if I liquidate this losing position I would not have to pay any taxes. (Ending balance $0 profit).

**Now the question:**

What if after selling the unrealised position I immediately buy the same exact position (and manage to get the same price).

Am I still on the hook to pay taxes or is my taxable amount still $0 for that year?

Comment: Please edit in to add a country tag and I will reopen question. Note: Member has asked other questions and not responded to this request. It's misguided for us to simply resort to a US-centric answer, and should refrain from answering until there's clarity.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica done.

Comment: Promise kept. Answers will be coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You will still owe taxes on your gains of $1000.**

This is covered by the [Wash-Sale Rule](https://www.fidelity.com/learning-center/personal-finance/wash-sales-rules-tax).

> The wash-sale rule prohibits selling an investment for a loss and
> replacing it with the same or a "substantially identical" investment
> 30 days before or after the sale.

This is not tax fraud, unless you claim the loss despite the rule.